# Getting Bash Error When Trying to Run start.sh for a Game

Tags: bash

The system I am running is Ubuntu 22.04 updated and upgraded, bash version 5.1.16.
I am trying to run a game from its directory and I get the following error:

```
dah@jellyfish:~/GOG Games/X3 Terran War Pack$ ls -afl
total 36
drwx------  6 dah dah 4096 Mar  2 10:08  .mojosetup
drwx------  2 dah dah 4096 Mar  2 10:04  docs
drwx------ 12 dah dah 4096 Mar  2 10:08  game
-rw-rw-r--  1 dah dah   76 Mar  2 10:08  gameinfo
-rwxrwxrwx  1 dah dah  538 Mar  2 10:32  start.sh
drwx------  6 dah dah 4096 Mar  2 10:32  .
-rwxr-xr-x  1 dah dah  437 Mar  2 10:08 'uninstall-X3 Terran War Pack.sh'
drwx------  3 dah dah 4096 Mar  2 10:04  ..
drwx------  4 dah dah 4096 Mar  2 10:08  support
dah@jellyfish:~/GOG Games/X3 Terran War Pack$ bash start.sh
Running X3: Terran War Pack
start.sh: line 20: ./X3TC_config: No such file or directory
```

Here is the location of `X3TC_config`:

`/home/dah/GOG Games/X3 Terran War Pack/game/X3TC_config`

As well as the permissions:

```
dah@jellyfish:~/GOG Games/X3 Terran War Pack$ ls -afl game | grep X3TC_config
-rwxrwxr-x  1 dah dah       5592 Mar  2 10:08 test_X3TC_config
-rwxrwxr-x  1 dah dah     502384 Mar  2 10:06 X3TC_config
```

The contents of `start.sh` seem to be correct as well:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# GOG.com (www.gog.com)
# Game

# Initialization 
CURRENT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )" 
cd "${CURRENT_DIR}" 
source support/gog_com.shlib 

# Game info 
GAME_NAME="$(get_gameinfo 1)" 
VERSION="$(get_gameinfo 2)" 
VERSION_DEV="$(get_gameinfo 3)" 

# Actions
run_game() { 
echo "Running ${GAME_NAME}" 
cd "${CURRENT_DIR}/game" 
chmod +x * 
 ./"X3TC_config" 

}
default() { 
run_game
} 

# Options
define_option "-s" "--start" "start ${GAME_NAME}" "run_game" "$@" 

# Defaults
standard_options "$@"
```

I have tried to get with support with no response, so I figured I would try my luck here. Any help is appreciated!

So I modify the script to test the current directory:

```
run_game() { 
echo "Running ${GAME_NAME}" 
echo "${CURRENT_DIR}"  # echo current dir
cd "${CURRENT_DIR}/game" 
chmod +x * 
 ./"X3TC_config" 

}
```

Save then run:

```
dah@jellyfish:~/GOG Games/X3 Terran War Pack$ bash start2.sh
Running X3: Terran War Pack
/home/dah/GOG Games/X3 Terran War Pack
start2.sh: line 21: ./X3TC_config: No such file or directory
```

The paths seem to be correct. Here is an example of another `start.sh` of a game that launches:

```
# Actions
run_game() {
    echo "Running ${GAME_NAME}"
    cd game
    chmod +x "PillarsOfEternity"
    ./"PillarsOfEternity"
}

default() {
  run_game
}
```

All of the code is the same except for the game name...

I have added `set -x` to step through the script, and here is the result:

```
+ run_game
+ echo 'Running X3: Terran War Pack'
Running X3: Terran War Pack
+ cd game
+ chmod +x 01.cat 01.dat 02.cat 02.dat 03.cat 03.dat 04.cat 04.dat 05.cat 05.dat 06.cat 06.dat 07.cat 07.dat 08.cat 08.dat 09.cat 09.dat 10.cat 10.dat 11.cat 11.dat 12.cat 12.dat 13.cat 13.dat addon addon2 background2ap.jpg background2fl.jpg background2.jpg config.gtkrc dds Documents gamepad.png goggame-1441039322.hashdb goggame-1441039322.id goggame-1441039322.info lang.dat lib loadscr mov 'Online Registration.url' res.dat scripts soundtrack t testandlaunch testcommon testfailed test_txc test_X3AP_config test_X3AP_main test_X3FL_config test_X3FL_main test_X3TC_config test_X3TC_main X3AP_config X3AP_main x3files.xml X3FL_config X3FL_main X3TC_config X3TC_main
+ ./X3TC_config
start.sh: line 20: ./X3TC_config: No such file or directory
```

It doesn't make any sense because `X3TC_config` is in fact in `/home/dah/GOG Games/X3 Terran War Pack/game`.

Comment: Doesn't the file name contain whitespace or hidden characters? Try `ls X3TC* | xxd` or any other hex dump.

Comment: @choroba [Parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) works here? I'd use `printf` instead since I'm not sure: `printf '%s' X3TC* | xxd`. (I'd use a loop but only one file is expected.)

Comment: I think choroba is on the right track, but if not, please make a [mre] including complete but minimal code. Here, `define_option` and `standard_options` aren't defined, probably because they're sourced from `support/gog_com.shlib`. Also try passing the script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fixing any problems it identifies.

Comment: Is this code you've written? If it's third-party code you downloaded, you should report the problem to the author.

Comment: @choroba Why would special characters be a problem? The script qutoes the variables.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script so you can see a trace of the commands being executed.

Comment: @Barmar: Because the code tries to run `./"X3TC_config"`, not `./"X3TC_config\r"` or whatever.

Comment: Try `ls -lb game | grep X3TC_config`. This will show special characters with escape sequences.

Comment: Here is the output of `printf '%s' X3TC* | xxd`:
`00000000: 5833 5443 2a                             X3TC*`

Comment: @abdullah Oh, you need to run it in the `game` folder for it to work. I.e. first do `cd '/home/dah/GOG Games/X3 Terran War Pack/game'`.

Comment: Ah yes, `/GOG Games/X3 Terran War Pack/game$ printf '%s' X3TC* | xxd'` => `00000000: 5833 5443 5f63 6f6e 6669 6758 3354 435f  X3TC_configX3TC_` and `00000010: 6d61 696e                                main`

Comment: @choroba I don't think there are special chars there..

Comment: @Barmar It is third party, support hasn't gotten to me in 3 days. I wanted to see if I could fix it myself.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the `set -x` output to my post and it successfully changes to the correct directory, but somehow cannot find `X3TC_config'...

Comment: Even when I use the explicit path to `X3TC_config` it still says the file doesn't exist.

Comment: If you do `file X3TC_config` what does it say?

Comment: `~/GOG Games/X3 Terran War Pack/game$ file X3TC_config
X3TC_config: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=cea3241ca126155ffffe9e34e8ffa213322d0ea1, stripped`

Comment: I have an AMD 64-bit.

Comment: The game only comes with 32-bit binaries...I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmar. You helped me figure it out!

Comment: That's a strange error message. I think it should say something about an unsupported executable format.

Comment: I agree! But all of the other game scripts are nearly identical and work. All of the other games are 64-bit. Even on the store web page for the game it says it only comes in 32-bit, I just overlooked it. I am going to install it on a 32-bit Ubuntu VM and see if it runs!

Comment: I am running it on Ubuntu 18.04 VM and it launches!